# Semichas haparshios between Shemini and Tazria

Tags: sources-mekorot, kashrut-kosher, chinuch-education, parashat-shemini, parashat-tazria

I have seen a fairly well-known dvar torah numerous times that links the end of the Parshas Shemini with the beginning of Parshas Tazria - but I am trying to find the source of it.

The vort is as follows:
Parshas Shemini concludes detailing the kosher animals and Parshas Tazria begins by talking about a woman who gave birth. The connection being that if one is careful about what a child eats, then they can become good, pure children.

I have heard it said in the name of the Ramban and this is indeed supported [here](https://jewishvues.com/articles/tazria-metzora/) but I can't seem to locate it in the Ramban inside? [Here](https://www.sie.org/templates/sie/article_cdo/aid/2865680/jewish/Dvar-Torah-Questions-and-Answers-on-Tazria.htm) it is b'sheim Rabbi Akiva Eiger?

Can anyone please help!

Comment: Any takers pleeeeeeeeeeeeeease!!!!